# How to create customer-coupon combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying in SQL Server, without success to create a customer-coupon combination. the raw data looks like that:

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzWYI.png)

The table goes on until 100 rows, it's a combination of 10 different customers, and 10 different coupons.

The desired result should look like this:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mari3.png)

My attempts so far wasn't close, I was using `row_number` and this next script:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        customer_id, coupon,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY coupon ORDER BY customer_id) rnk 
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE rnk = 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYIvx.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow the logic here as you don't describe it; just post 2 image and expect us to work it out. What have *you* tried to solve the problem as well? Why didn't it work?

Comment: "I'm trying" - please show us what you have tried? Also its preferred it you don't use images for data, instead use formatted text, or DDL+DML.

Comment: I'm trying to get a distinct coupon for each customer, there are 10 distinct copuons and 10 distinct customers. picture 1 is the table I'm working on and table 2 is what I'm trying to reach.

Comment: Put your attempts in the question, @BarKarako , along with the explanation of the logic you're trying to achieve, by using the [edit] feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess, if I am reading between the lines correctly is to use a couple of `DENSE_RANK`'s. This isn't tested though, as images of data don't help us help you as we can't copy the text/data out of them:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       sq1.CustomerID
       sq2.coupon
FROM (SELECT YT.CustomerID,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YT.CustomerID) AS DR
      FROM dbo.YourTable YT) sq1
     JOIN (SELECT YT.Coupon,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YT.Coupon) AS DR
           FROM dbo.YourTable YT) sq2 ON sq1.DR = sq2.DR;
```

Comment: your best guess was AMAZING! that just worked! thank you!